# How to rollback DB transaction after http connection is lost

Tags: servlets, transactions, httpwebrequest, commit, rollback

Recently at a interview the interviewer asked me a question, below is the question -

Suppose a request is sent to a servlet and the servlet performs several DB transactions(first update and commit, then read and update and again commit) which takes around 3-4 minutes, during that period the user press the cancel button and the connection is lost. How would you rollback the entire transaction.

My answer was - Since Servlet throws IOException we can handle the exception and rollback the transaction.

But again he questioned me what about the DB commits which are already done, how would you rollback that.

I was blank and replied that i never came across that situation. But i would really like to know what could be done in such a situation.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you commit transaction while servlet working. Is it possible to do all work in one transaction?

Most database engines support nested transactions. Try to open outer main transaction before your servlet start his work. If you catch an exception you can roll back this transaction.

Comment: @Nicolai : i told interviewer about this solution but still he did not agree

Answer (score 0):

> But again he questioned me what about the DB commits which are already
>   done, how would you rollback that.

I think it was not a servlet related questions.If the transaction was committed in the database you can not rollback it. A database transaction has several properties known as [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability). The one that applies in this case is [Durability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durability_%28database_systems%29):

> "Durability is the ACID property which guarantees that transactions
>   that have committed will survive permanently"